# Stochastic Schrödinger Equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I have a stochastic coupled Schrödinger equation to solve.

$$i\frac{\mathrm d X_k(t)}{\mathrm dt}=-\left(x_{k+1}(t)+x_{k-1}(t)\right)+V_k x_k(t)+\eta_k t x_k(t)$$

where $\left\langle\eta_k(t)\eta_j(t^\prime)\right\rangle=\delta_{k,j}\theta(\tau-|t-t^\prime|)$ and $\theta(t)$ is Heaviside theta.

It is a coupled equation of $n$ variables and $n$ could be any number. In my case $n$ is typically 100-200.So there are 100-200 coupled differential equations. $\eta_k(t)$ is a random function of $\mathrm{time}(t)$ which is, in my case a gaussian random variable corresponding to the variable $x_k$. Different $\eta_k$ are unrelated. $V_k$ is a fixed number corresponding to the variable $X_k$. I don't know how to solve this stochastic differential equation.Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you write down your equations?. What have you tried with Mathematica?

Comment: Well start small. Do you know how to write the code for n=1? If not, your question is actually about solving SDEs in general.

Comment: There was a picture OP forgot to include. I transcribed the equations in it as best as I can.

Comment: Is this even about _Mathematica_?

Comment: " I don't know how to solve this stochastic differential equation.Can anybody help me?" There is a book: Risken, H. The Fokker-Plank Equation. Methods of Solution and Applications. 2 edn,  (Springer-Verlag, 1989). There it is written, how to deal with them. Have fun!

Comment: I tried with NDSolve..I wrote the differential equation and put it inside NDSolve. and it worked for n=1..but didn't work for large values..let's say n=50 or more..it gave errors like  'Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}. >>' ,which is also saying ' In some versions of the Wolfram Language, an error occurs because this differential equation does not have a solution:'....

Comment: The main question is how to solve this kind of stochastic differential equation in Mathematica??

Comment: `NDSolve` definitely will not work here.  Instead, check [Stochastic Differential Equation Processes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StochasticDifferentialEquationProcesses.html).